# Skip RLS checks temporarily

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I have tables with enabled row-level-security and the relevant policies in place - working really well.

My problem is that sometimes, based on some conditions, I want to bypass a policy for a specific statement during a function execution.

something like:

```
...
statement 1
statement 2
if (some cond) then
   disable rls temporarily 
   statement 3 -- mostly delete rows the user can't normally see
   enable rls
else
   statement 3
end if
```

The way I've implemented it is by creating a function `check_cond` which returns a boolean evaluating `some cond` and created an additional select policy which calls this `check_cond`.

It works - but the actual problem is that the query `select * from tab` now looks like this:
`select * from tab where <original policy condition> or check_cond()`

This `or check_cond()` causes postges to always do a full table scan since it cannot evaluate the result pre-planning.

If I were able to write "dynamic" code in the policy I would have been able to add/remove conditions based on the value of `check_cond()` but as far as I know it's not possible.

Any smart way which would allow me to temporarily disable rls or dynamically add conditions  without sacrificing performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have a `SECURITY DEFINER` function owned by a superuser which runs:

```
ALTER ROLE someuser BYPASSRLS;
```

where `someuser` is the user that runs the SQL statements.

Afterwards, you can re-enable it in the same way.

But that's pretty insecure, because nothing keeps the user from calling theses functions at other times.

A better way would be to define a security definer function owned by a user with `BYPASSRLS` that does the deletes for you.

**Note:** for security reasons, **always** `SET search_path` when you define a `SECURITY DEFINER` function.

Comment: "A better way would be to define a security definer function owned by a user with BYPASSRLS that does the deletes for you." - security definer is the magic word I was looking for - this should do the trick - thanks! Will accept once I get it working